# Add direct tab links inside a Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, post, tabs

To create tabs inside a post, I already use [the custom fields plug-in](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).
This plug-in, perfectly user friendly, works great and I would like to keep it.

Here is a screen-shot of these post tabs inside my Wordpress admin dashboard.

[image]

Here is the display of a post:

[image]

However, this plug-in isn't adding to the url the path of these tabs.
Currently, I'm unable to get a direct link of a post with a selected open tab.

I'm looking for this url result: `http://xxxx/categorie/title-of-my-post/tab1`

Any ideas or solution?

Note: The Wordpress dashboard will be used by a client, so adding content must be as convenient as possible, **any convenient solution is accepted.**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

hello you can open specific tab by url just use like this your-link/categorie/title-of-my-post/#tab1

if tab1 is id for tab1 if you can provide your website url i can provide exact url

but here is a example :-

http://kav.in/wp-ui-for-wordpress/#accordion

Comment: +1 for your answer, but I'm looking for this url: http://xxxx/categorie/title-of-my-post/tab1
(no choice)

Comment: yes you can do it that also .... you need something like this http://goo.gl/VQKTu every tab has its own link .... can you provide your site url so i can check the tab .....

Answer (score 1):

The "Tabs" in ACF don't actually create content tables in the database. They are only for layout of data entry in the back-end. So when calling your field "text" from "Tab 1", you would only need to do **the_field('text')** on your template to call it in.

You'll need to wrap your called field within the tab on your page template. This would have nothing to do with ACF and instead your template.

```
<ul id="tabbed-nav">
     <li class="tab-1">Your field called <em>text</em>: <?php the_field('text'); ?></li>
     <li class="tab-2">Your second Tab Content <?php the_field('text_tab2'); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yep, the tabs is like the message field... just to layout stuff in the back-end.

Comment: Retrieving the data ins't an issue, but what I want is redirecting the user to another page when we change tabs

Comment: If you're looking to make navigation with a system like this instead of a traditional nav system, then you can set up page templates and use [link]http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-get-values-from-another-page/ . This would get you values from just one page. If this is the route you're intending to go, I suggest you purchase the Options plugin to make it even cleaner for the client.

Answer (score 1):

That's because that plugin dont have "links url" written in their code.

Try these plugins instead

a. http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-side-tab/  add links to any page.

b. http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ui/

Answer (score 0):

I made a little demo.

With the ACF plugin I made a fieldgroup with 3 fields called: tab1, tab2 & tab3. I gave the group rules so they are visible on the page "[tabtest (working demo)](http://develop.cpp.nl/?page_id=42)".

For the demo I used [Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) from the jQuery UI. I didn't go to the trouble of putting the js on the correct place due the current footer and header are used for another demo.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">

        <div id="content" role="main">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div id="tabs-1"><p><?php the_field('tab1');?></p></div>
                <div id="tabs-2"><p><?php the_field('tab2');?></p></div>
                <div id="tabs-3"><p><?php the_field('tab3');?></p></div>
            </div>

            <script>
                $(function() {
                    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
                });
            </script>

        </div><!-- #content -->

    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```